# Manual on translating Caffe's "message" from caffe.proto to "layer" in .prototxt

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, protocol-buffers, caffe

Consider Caffe's [manual page about fully connected layer](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/innerproduct.html).

It contains sample, starting with the word `layer`, describing corresponding lines in the `.prototxt` file. It also contains a fragment from the `caffe.proto`.

This linked manual page is more or less elaborated and helpful. Others are less verbose, for example [HDF5 Data Layer](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html).

My question is - how can I use given excerpts from `caffe.proto` to construct respective `layer` in my `.prototxt`?

Where is the description of correspondence between `caffe.proto` and `.prototxt`?

The same question arises about many other entries in `caffe.proto`: `NetParameter`, `TransformationParameter`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Caffe is using [Google's protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) format to store net parameters and configurations (.prototxt and .binaryproto files). The file `caffe.ptoto` is the specification of protocol buffer format caffe is using.

Read the linked tutorial of Google's protobuf to understand how `caffe.proto` syntax is translated to layer definitions and parameters appearing in the prototxt files of caffe.

Comment: This link contains code, but I was interested in manual creation of prototxt files.